# How do I set up a context for Apache Tomcat that is not located in the web-apps folder

Tags: java, tomcat

I am wanting to set up 2 context paths for my Tomcat server, but I do not want to have to deploy a separate war file each time. I know that once upon a time I could have a context folder that was outside of the webapps folder in my Tomcat instance. If I am still able to do this all I would have to do is restart my tomcat session so that the changes would be recognized.

I have been reading the Tomcat documentation 8.5.43 Apache Tomcat 8 Configuration Reference. I understand the words but I am just getting more and more confused.

This is what I want.

This is the container for my application root
C:\myFoo\index.jsp

This is how I want to access the above in my web browser.
localhost:8080\myFoo\index.jsp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See section [Defining a context](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/context.html#Defining_a_context):

> Individual Context elements may be explicitly defined:
>
> In individual files (with a ".xml" extension) in the `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/[enginename]/[hostname]/` directory. The context path and version will be derived from the base name of the file (the file name less the .xml extension). This file will always take precedence over any context.xml file packaged in the web application's META-INF directory.

So, create file `.../conf/catalina/localhost/myFoo.xml` with content:

```xml
<Context docBase="C:/myFoo" />
```

Create another file `.../conf/catalina/localhost/myFoo2.xml` with same content.

Now `localhost:8080\myFoo\index.jsp` and `localhost:8080\myFoo2\index.jsp` will see the same content, even though they are two differently loaded webapps (double memory use).

Comment: Is localhost the engine parameter? I believe that foo is the host name? If so the foo.xml that is sitting in the webapps folder sits outside of an individual folder, right? So this then would be true in this example. localhost = webapps folder in the tomcat configuration.

Comment: @MichaelBrown *"Is localhost the engine parameter?"* No, with directory `/conf/[enginename]/[hostname]/`, the example `/conf/catalina/localhost/myFoo.xml` means that `localhost` is the **`[hostname]`**, i.e. the `<Host name="localhost" ...>` element in the server.xml file. --- *"I believe that foo is the host name?"* There is no `foo`, but `myFoo` is the *context path*. --- *"the foo.xml that is sitting in the webapps folder"* There should be no xml files in the `webapps` folder itself.

Comment: I apologize, what you are saying makes sense on one level. However, I have been testing and evaluating software for much longer than I have been developing the software. I am forcing myself to learn how to do this. You have given me good advice, but I am not benefiting from this.  This is what I know and what I have learned. In the conf/server.xml it identifies <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost"> Further down it defines the <Host name="localhost" appBase="webapps" ...> This I userstand points to the ROOT folder in webapps which points to the index.jsp.

Comment: I am confused as to what folder localhost is. I found one in the Catalina folder in the conf folder but there are no other files  in this folder. My endgame is to have a context that is set up outside of the $CATALINA_BASE so I do not have to create a WAR file initially. I know that eventually this will be my goal. I am not there yet. I feel like I have a hundred miles to go before that step.  Thanks for your help

Comment: If you're doing virtual hosting (you're not), there will be more than one `<Host>` element. Any unknown host name will use the `defaultHost` value, i.e. `localhost`, so without virtual hosting, Tomcat will use the `<Host name="localhost" ...>` regardless of the host name used in the imcoming request URL. --- The `appBase="webapps"` identifies the folder were .war files (or folders) should be put. The .war file name is the *context path*. For more information, see [Automatic Application Deployment](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/host.html#Automatic_Application_Deployment).

Comment: As an alternative to placing .war file in the `webapps` folder, you can add a context .xml file to the `/conf/Catalina/localhost` folder. This is what you need, since you want Tomcat to serve two different *context path* using the same .war file, and that is what I've described in my answer. Read the Tomcat Documentation in the various links I've provided to learn more.